# Programming a live looper with Audiokit?

Tags: audiokit

Hello to all audiokit users,
(I hope this is the right place to ask my question)

I am willing to make a live looping app for ios, mostly because I just can't find what I need in the other currently existing apps.

I am considering the Audiokit framework to do so, for it is very well documented, accessible, user friendly,...

Although, before starting from scratch I wished to have the input of more experienced users than myself:

Is Audiokit adapted for this kind of application? Until now most of the apps I have seen are more 'Synth-like' apps.

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Here are two examples of looping apps in the app store built with AudioKit:

**Jam Looper**
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jam-looper-music-maker/id1061465697?mt=8

**Loop Maker**
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/loop-maker-amazing-music-maker/id1196282854

Hope that is helpful,

Comment: And now there's even the AudioKit L7 Looper: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/audiokit-l7-live-looper/id1485507635